# Which Gradle version shall be used for classpath after upgrading of android studio and plugins to 4.2.2?

Tags: android-studio

After upgrading android studio from 4.1.3 to 4.2.2 and plugins, the line in `build.gradle` causes the error:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'  //<<==which gradle version shall be used here?
    }
```

The error is:

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':aliyun-oss-react-native:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :aliyun-oss-react-native

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

What is the correct version of gradle used for `classpath`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project Structure settings and update gradle version to `6.7.1+`version and let it download and then build project again.

**For more information** about Gradle and plugin versions check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin